# Doesn't cout output from left to right?

Tags: c++, function, codeblocks, cout

So my professor gave an assignment and he gave the `main()` function to follow. We are to come up with the class for it to produce similar output. I tried a lot of code but I can't get the answer. And when the professor sent me his answer, I can't seem to understand it.

This is the question,

> Create a program for displaying the parameter of three shapes namely circle, triangle and square.
>   The class should be able to request the user to insert relevant information for each shape namely the length and diameter which will be stored in a private member of the class. The parameter of each shape will be stored in a variable called SParameter which is assigned as a private member. The `main()` is to be fixed.

So here's my professor's,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class shape {
    private:
    string name;
    double length;
    double Tperimeter;

    public:
    void perimeter()
    {
    if (name == "circle")
    {
        cout<<"enter  the diameter:";
        cin>>length;
       Tperimeter = 3.142* length;
    }
    if (name == "triangle")
    {
       cout<<"enter side length:";
        cin>>length;
       Tperimeter = 3*length;
    }
    if (name == "square")
    {
       cout<<"enter side length:";
        cin>>length;
       Tperimeter = 4*length;
    }
    }

    double display(string shapename)
    {
    name=shapename;
    if (name == "circle")
    {
    perimeter();
    return Tperimeter;
    }
    if (name == "triangle")
    {
    perimeter();
    return Tperimeter;
    }
    if (name == "square")
    {
    perimeter();
    return Tperimeter;
    }
    } };

int main() {
    shape S;
    char c;
    string name;
    do
    {
    cout<<"Enter name of shape:";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"the perimeter of "<<name<<"is:"<< S.display(name)<<endl;
    cout<<"do you wish to continue?";
    cin>    c;
    }while(c!='n');

    return 0; }
```

and here is my code,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class shape{ private:
    int Sparameter;
    int perimeter;
    string name; public:
    shape(){

        }
    int display(string name){
          if(name=="circle"){
            cout<<"Enter the diameter of the circle";
            cin>>Sparameter;
            perimeter=3.14*Sparameter/2;
        }
        else if(name=="square"){
            cout<<"Enter the length of the square";
            cin>>Sparameter;
            perimeter=4*Sparameter;
        }
        else if(name=="triangle"){
            cout<<"Enter the length of the triangle";
            cin>>Sparameter;
            perimeter=3*Sparameter;
       return perimeter;
        }

        } };

int main() {
    shape S;
    char c;
    string name;
    do
    {
    cout<<"Enter name of shape:";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"the perimeter of "<<name<<"is:"<< S.display(name)<<endl;
    cout<<"do you wish to continue?";
    cin>>    c;
    }while(c!='n');

    return 0; }
```

So my question is on the output, if using Codeblocks, this is the output for both me and my professors' code.

> Enter name of shape:circle
>   the perimeter of circleis:enter  the diameter:10
>   31.42
>   do you wish to continue?

The cout of "perimeter of circle" will appear before the "enter the diameter". However if I use an online compiler such as online gdb. It's output is different for my professor's code.

> Enter name of shape:circle
>   enter  the diameter:30
>   the perimeter of circleis:94.26
>   do you wish to continue?

The" enter the diameter "part will appear before "the perimeter of a circle", even though in the cout section "the perimeter of a circle" comes before the calling of the S.display() function.

> cout<<"the perimeter of "<

So how does the enter the diameter appear first? I asked my professor this and he said the key is calling a function within a function. But that doesn't explain much for me, am I missing something?  Isn't the flow of the program from left to right?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove everything but the code you need help with. Your professor has provided something to guide you. We (I) don't care. Ask a specific question. Are you using a debugger? How far do you get? What output do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: If that's your professor's example code then they have no business teaching a course on C++.

Comment: I mean, we could analyze this, but the true issue is that having a reading operation as a side effect within a printing operation should not be a thing in the first place. A method `display` should do exactly that, printing the information. And you should separate IO-operations and the inner logic. It should look like this: 1. Routine that asks for input and stores it in variables. 2. Constructor of your class which takes those. 3. Methods of your class which access the values being called. 4. The retrieved values being printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class shape{ private:
    double Sparameter;
    double perimeter;
    string name; public:
    shape(){

        }
    double display(string name){
          if(name=="circle"){
            cout<<"Enter the diameter of the circle: ";
            cin>>Sparameter;
            perimeter=3.14*Sparameter/2;
        }
        else if(name=="square"){
            cout<<"Enter the length of the square: ";
            cin>>Sparameter;
            perimeter=4*Sparameter;
        }
        else if(name=="triangle"){
            cout<<"Enter the length of the triangle: ";
            cin>>Sparameter;
            perimeter=3*Sparameter;
       return perimeter;
        }

        } };

int main() {
    shape S;
    char c;
    string name;
    do
    {
    cout<<"Enter name of shape:";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"the perimeter of "<<name<<"is:"<< S.display(name)<<endl;
    cout<<"do you wish to continue?";
    cin>>    c;
    }while(c!='n');

    return 0; }
```

I think try this code, I tried this on my compiler/text editor (Atom) and an online compiler. I just changed the types to double since you will be dealing with floats

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the C++17 language revision, both results are actually legal.  The order in which an operator's operands get evaluated was not specified before C++17.

Let's break down this expression:

```
cout<<"the perimeter of "<<name<<"is:"<< S.display(name)<<endl;
//                                     ^
//                                     |
//                                     I'm going to focus on this << operator
```

Because the order in which operands get evaluated was unspecified, the compiler could choose to evaluate either the left or right hand side of the marked operator first.  The evaluation of both operands has side-effects (namely printing output), so those side-effects could appear in either order.

- If the compiler chose to evaluate the left-hand side (`cout<<"the perimeter of "<<name<<"is:"`) first, its output would appear first and you would see output like

```
Enter name of shape:circle
the perimeter of circleis:enter the diameter:10
31.42
do you wish to continue?
```

- If the compiler chose to evaluate the right-hand side (`S.display(name)`) first then its output would appear first and you would see output like

```
Enter name of shape:circle
enter the diameter:30
the perimeter of circleis:94.26
do you wish to continue?
```

---

C++17 rectified all this.  Operands are now required to be evaluated from left-to-right, so if you compile with a C++17 compliant compiler you will always see output like

```
Enter name of shape:circle
the perimeter of circleis:enter the diameter:10
31.42
do you wish to continue?
```

The compiler *cannot* choose to evaluate `S.display(name)` before `cout<<"the perimeter of "<<name<<"is:"`.

---

This explains the different output you're seeing.  Your local compiler chose to evaluate the left-hand-side of the `<<` operator first and the online compiler chose to evaluate the right-hand-side first.

Comment: Thanks , so it's more to do with the compiler, and nothing to do with the function in function right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "function in function".  Since the order of evaluation of your `<<` operator's operands is unspecified then it could change based on your compiler, compiler version, compiler options, phase of the moon, etc.

Comment: I meant that like in my professors code, inside S.display() he has another perimeter(), but after your explanation it makes sense to me now, thanks !